# Estimate dynamic scheduling overhead in OpenMP: Is the overhead of every directive the same?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, scheduling, overhead

I would like to predict/estimate the scheduling overhead of OpenMP. For this reason I do some microbenchmarks measuring the scheduling time of a few directives.

For example I create a for loop with 8 chunks, for which the dynamic scheduling is obvious (using 4 cores)

```
for(i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
      sleep(i*1)
    }
```

The assignment should be something like this: CPU0: i=0 and i=4, CPU1: i=2 and i=6, CPU2 i=1 and i=5, CPU3: i=3 and i=7

Assume the overall scheduling overhead I measured is 8 seconds. Can I assume, that the scheduling overhead for every single directive is 1 second? And furthermore may I consequently assume the overall scheduling overhead = 1000s for a loop with 1000 iterations?

Comment: What data have you gathered from your experiments to investigate this matter ?  For my money you can make whatever assumptions you want, but in this domain data trumps assumptions.  Every time.

Comment: No the overhead is not the same for each scheduling. If your data is regular static is a better fit than dynamic.

Comment: You should at least consider existing OpenMP microbenchmarks like EPCC https://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/research/computing/performance-characterisation-and-benchmarking/epcc-openmp-micro-benchmark-suite One can argue about their utility, and whether they measure the right thing (barrier rate is uninteresting, last-in to first-out is interesting), but surveying what exists is a sensible place to start.